# Stop downstream of LiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I'm using `Transformations` to [change](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata) the `Livedata` under certains conditions.

I would like to know if is posible to stop the downstream of starsLD under some condition without stop observing it(i.e. using removeObserver).

I have the following code:

```
private val sss = StarsFBLiveData()
val starsLD : LiveData<Pair<Int,Long>>  = Transformations.map(sss) {
    tuple ->

        gamesLD.value?.let {
            var i = 0
            for(game in it){
                if(game.id==tuple.first){
                    return@map Pair(i,tuple.second)
                }
            }
        }

        return@map null
    }
```

Comment: `"to stop the downstream [...] without stop observing it."` - what you mean by that?

Comment: I don't want to use `removeObserver` to stop the downstream from livedata.